# Multiple Gridview in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, grid

I want to use 2 Gridview in one page
First gridview should be displayed on page load and 2nd should be showed  on click on link button inside 1st gridview in every row

1st gridview in design

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcancelingedit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit" DataKeyNames="Class_ID,Class_ShortName" 
        onrowdeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvDetails_RowEditing" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging"
        onrowupdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating" CssClass="grid">
            <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class ID" Visible="false">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Class_id") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ControlStyle-Width="80px">
         <ItemTemplate>

             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  OnClick="selectrow"  CommandArgument = "LinkButton1" Text='<%#Eval("Class_id") %>'> </asp:LinkButton> 
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>




         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enrolment Fee" ControlStyle-Width="100px" >
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Enrolment_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a21" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Enrolment_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Costume Fee"  >
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Costume_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a31" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Costume_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DSA Academy Fee" ControlStyle-Width="80px">
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DSA_Academy_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a41" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DSA_Academy_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ensemble1 Fee" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble1_fee") %>' />
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a51" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble1_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ensemble2 Fee"  ControlStyle-Width="100px">
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble2_fee") %>' />
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a61" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble2_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ensemble3 Fee" ControlStyle-Width="80px" >
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble3_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a71" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ensemble3_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StarzTroop Eisteddfod Fee"  >
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a8" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Straztroop_Eisteddfod_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a81" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Straztroop_Eisteddfod_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StrazTroop Workshops Fee" ControlStyle-Width="80px">
         <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="a9" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Straztroop_4Workshops_per_year_fee") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="a91" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Straztroop_4Workshops_per_year_fee") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>


         <asp:TemplateField>
        <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/update.jpg" ToolTip="Update" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/img/Cancel.jpg" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/Edit.jpg" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/delete.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete This?');"/>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

2nd gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" DataKeyNames="Class_ID" 
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging"
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" CssClass="grid">
        <Columns>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class ID" Visible="true">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("class_id") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>   
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total_fee" ControlStyle-Width="100px" >
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Total_fee") %>'/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a21" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Total_fee") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weekly_fee"  >
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Weekly_fee") %>'/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a31" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Weekly_fee") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fort_night_fee" ControlStyle-Width="80px">
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fort_night_fee") %>'/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a41" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fort_night_fee") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monthly_fee" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Monthly_fee") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a51" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Monthly_fee") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Term_fee"  ControlStyle-Width="100px">
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Term_fee") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a61" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Term_fee") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Classes_per_week" ControlStyle-Width="80px" >
     <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="a7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Classes_per_week") %>'/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="a71" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Classes_per_week") %>'/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/update.jpg" ToolTip="Update" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/img/Cancel.jpg" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/Edit.jpg" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/delete.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete This?');"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

this is C# code behind it

```
private int classid;
    private bool recordexist=false;
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EnrolmentSystem"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Binddropdown3();

            Loaddata();
        }
    }
    private void Binddropdown3()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_Class  order by Class_ID asc ", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList3.DataSource = dr;
            DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("--Select Class--");
            DropDownList3.DataTextField = "Class_Name";
            DropDownList3.DataValueField = "Class_ID";
            DropDownList3.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        string s = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        SqlCommand cmmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Tbl_Class.Class_ID from Tbl_Class where Tbl_Class.Class_Name='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader reader1 = cmmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader1.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                classid = reader1.GetInt32(0);
            }
            reader1.Close();


            SqlCommand cmmmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Class_id from Tbl_Class_fee where Class_id='" +classid+ "'", con);
            SqlDataReader r1 = cmmmd1.ExecuteReader();

            if (r1.HasRows)
            {
                recordexist = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                recordexist=false;
            }

            r1.Close();

            if (recordexist == true)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_Fee_payment_packges values('" + classid + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + "')", con);
                cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
                lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblresult.Text = "Basic Fee of this Class is already Entered.You just need to enter the package detail of this class";
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_Fee_payment_packges values('" + classid + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tbl_Class_fee values('" + classid + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + TextBox13.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "')", con);
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                con.Close();
                lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblresult.Text = "Your Information Saved Successfully";
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Loaddata()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            ("SELECT dbo.Tbl_Class_fee.*, dbo.Tbl_Class.* FROM dbo.Tbl_Class,Tbl_Class_fee where Tbl_Class.Class_ID = Tbl_Class_fee.Class_id ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
            int columncount = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox a1 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a2");
        TextBox a2 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a3");
        TextBox a3 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a4");
        TextBox a4 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a5");
        TextBox a5 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a6");
        TextBox a6 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a7");
        TextBox a7 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a8");
        TextBox a8 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a9");
        TextBox a9 = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a10");


        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Tbl_Class_fee set Enrolment_fee='" + a1.Text + "',Costume_fee='" + a2.Text + "',DSA_Academy_fee='" + a3.Text + "',Ensemble1_fee='" + a4.Text + "',Ensemble2_fee='" + a5.Text + "',Ensemble3_fee='" + a6.Text + "',Straztroop_Eisteddfod_fee='" + a7.Text + "',Straztroop_4Workshops_per_year_fee='" + a8.Text +  "' where Class_ID=" + userid, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        lblresult.Text = " Details Updated successfully";
        gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        int  ProgramDescription = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Tbl_Class_fee where Class_id=" + userid, con);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            Loaddata();
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblresult.Text = ProgramDescription + " details deleted successfully";
        }
    }

    protected void gvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gvDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Loaddata();
        }
        catch { }
    }





    protected void selectrow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        classid=Convert.ToInt32(btn.Text);
        string CommandName = btn.CommandName;
        string CommandArgument = btn.CommandArgument;
        Loaddata1();
    }


    protected void Loaddata1()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            ("SELECT dbo.Tbl_Fee_payment_packges.* FROM Tbl_Fee_payment_packges where Tbl_Fee_payment_packges.class_id='" + classid + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;

            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox a1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a2");
        TextBox a2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a3");
        TextBox a3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a4");
        TextBox a4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a5");
        TextBox a5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a6");
        TextBox a6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a7");
        TextBox a7 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a8");
        TextBox a8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a9");
        TextBox a9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("a10");


        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Tbl_Class_fee set Enrolment_fee='" + a1.Text + "',Costume_fee='" + a2.Text + "',DSA_Academy_fee='" + a3.Text + "',Ensemble1_fee='" + a4.Text + "',Ensemble2_fee='" + a5.Text + "',Ensemble3_fee='" + a6.Text + "',Straztroop_Eisteddfod_fee='" + a7.Text + "',Straztroop_4Workshops_per_year_fee='" + a8.Text + "' where Class_ID=" + userid, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        lblresult.Text = " Details Updated successfully";
        gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        Loaddata();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        int ProgramDescription = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Tbl_Class_fee where Class_id=" + userid, con);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            Loaddata();
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblresult.Text = ProgramDescription + " details deleted successfully";
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Loaddata();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: What problem or issue are you getting?

Comment: doesn't show the 2nd grid on click

Comment: please refer this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: sir i don't need to show in nested grid .....i  want to show 2 grids on one page

Comment: why you not using the rowcommand as suggested @Renju Nair in answer

Comment: sir i am already using command argument.... every thing is fine in debugging  ...but it doesn't display the 2nd grid ....when i click on link button ... ...i don't know whats wrong with this

Comment: make sure your select query get back with some records from db if no record then gird will not show. Your code looks fine and working.

Comment: yes sir  select query has a record value

Comment: your code is fine. May be some java script or css causing the problem. Can you share page link to check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the LinkButton details as below

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CommandName="bind"     CommandArgument = "<%#Eval("Class_id") %>" Text='<%#Eval("Class_id") %>'> </asp:LinkButton>
```

and in code behind

```
protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.CommandName == "bind")
     {
       Loaddata1(); 
     }

  }
```

Hope This help